# How do I get Linq to return identical repeated rows only once?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm still pretty new to this, so go easy on me. I'm trying to get linq to return a single record when the query returns multiple identical records. Here's what I have:

```
var query = (from i in _db.BizListView
            let dist = DbGeography.FromText(i.Point).Distance(DbGeography.FromText(geog)) * .0006214
            where
                dist <= rng &&
                i.Name.Contains(key) &&
                pri != -1 ? (i.BizCategoryID == pri && i.Primary == true) : true &&
                biz != -1 ? (i.BizCategoryID == biz) : true  
            group i by new
            {
                ClientID = i.ClientID,
                Name = i.Name,
                Address = i.Address,
                Address1 = i.City + ", " + i.StateID + " " + i.PostCode,
                BizPhone = i.BizPhone,
                EmailAddress = i.EmailAddress,
                ClientImagePath = i.ClientImagePath,
                Distance = DbGeography.FromText(i.Point).Distance(DbGeography.FromText(geog)) * 0.0006214
            }
            into myTable                                                  
            orderby myTable.Key.Distance ascending
            select new 
            {
                ClientID = myTable.Key.ClientID,
                Name = myTable.Key.Name,
                Address = myTable.Key.Address,
                Address1 = myTable.Key.Address1,
                BizPhone = myTable.Key.BizPhone,
                EmailAddress = myTable.Key.EmailAddress,
                ClientImagePath = myTable.Key.ClientImagePath,
                Distance = myTable.Key.Distance                            
            }).Distinct();

return query;
```

The query produces a single record for each client, as long as a BizCategory is specified, but returns multiple identical records per client (a record for each of the Client's BizCategories) if no BizCategory is specified. How can I get the query to return a single record per client, instead of multiple identical records when no BizCategory is specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah!! All I had to do was add an additional conditional!

```
var query = from i in _db.BizListView
            let dist = DbGeography.FromText(i.Point).Distance(DbGeography.FromText(geog)) * 0.0006214
            where
                dist <= rng &&
                i.Name.Contains(key) &&
                pri != -1 ? (i.BizCategoryID == pri && i.Primary == true) : true &&
                biz != -1 ? (i.BizCategoryID == biz) : true &&
                (biz == -1 && pri == -1) ? (i.Primary == true): true               
            orderby i.Distance ascending
            select i;
```

Oh well. Live and learn.

Comment: You see? Each Client has multiple BizCategories, but only one BizCategory is marked as Primary. The pri variable was the Primary BizCategory, used by those searching for a Client whose Primary BizCategory was pri. The biz variable was used by those searching for any Client who does business in the biz BizCategory.
Each Client can have multiple BizCategories, but only one Primary BizCategory, so, if anyone searches for all Clients (therefore leaving pri and biz at -1), and I want to return each Client only once, I set Primary to true and get a single record returned for each Client.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that operator precedence is affecting the query.

Try adding parentheses around the ternary operators.

```
(pri != -1 ? (i.BizCategoryID == pri && i.Primary == true) : true) &&
(biz != -1 ? (i.BizCategoryID == biz) : true)
```

A simpler way to express this condition could be:

```
(pri == -1 || i.BizCategoryID == pri) &&
(biz == -1 || i.BizCategoryID == biz)
```

The way it *was* interpreted:

```
pri != -1 
    ? (i.BizCategoryID == pri && i.Primary == true)
    : (true && (biz != -1 ? (i.BizCategoryID == biz) : true))
            |< ----- IGNORED ----------------------------->|
```

You can see that the `true && biz != -1...` took precedence here. As `true` was evaluated first, the `biz` was never evaluated.

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do, Ed. The query is based on a view built on several one to many joins. The input to the query can be the BizCategoryID as either pri, or biz, but not both, or it can be neither. The query works exactly as I want it to as long as it is furnished either pri or biz. If it is furnished neither, it returns identical records for each BizCategory the client belongs to.